# How to reflect changes made to a cobol DB2 stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, cobol, mainframe, db2-zos

I'm getting a -805 when trying to run the changed stored procedure. The bind process that is done is: stop stored procedure, compile and bind stored proc, start stored procedure, refresh wlm area.

I still get a -805. I've tried displaying some things in the  stored procedure but those changes are not reflected. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here is what that error code means: DBRM OR PACKAGE NAME location-name.collection-id.dbrm-name.consistency-token NOT FOUND IN PLAN plan-name. REASON reason-code so check your DB2 plan

Comment: The bind issue should be for the DB2 operations.My issue is that the displays that I have placed in the stored procedure are not happening.

Comment: Your displays are not showing because your stored procedure is not executing because of the -805. Fix that and you should be OK. Have you followed the set processes of your establishment? And checked your error messages and return codes?

Comment: No,the displays are placed before the DB2 calls. It was previously working, with displays before the db2 call showing. Yes I have followed it. The error is a -805 I am trying to display the SQLERRMC content to be able to fix the -805 , which should work as the displays are before the call to the abend routine.

Comment: sounds like you compiled/are running from the wrong loadlib. Or if its an online module, a missed new copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind should be done after WLM refresh.